# Win32's FindWindow() can find a particular window with the exact title, but what about "try.bat - Notepad"?

Tags: ruby, winapi

Win32's `FindWindow()` can find a window having the title of "Untitled - Notepad", but what if I just want to find a Notepad window but don't know whether it is "try.bat - Notepad" or some other file name on the title bar?

It seems that if the title is passed in a NULL value, then any window will be returned, but only one window is returned, so there is no way to `grep` for the title using regular expression.

(I am doing this using Ruby's Win32API)

Comment: i'm surprised that this question was favorited 3 times and it didn't have a single upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would follow Eric's advice to use EnumWindows. You *can* provide Ruby callbacks to Windows API functions through win32-api. Here's an example that was trivially modified from the sample in the [win32-api README](http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/62627/win32-api-1.4.5.zip):

```
require 'win32/api'
include Win32

# Callback example - Enumerate windows
EnumWindows     = API.new('EnumWindows', 'KP', 'L', 'user32')
GetWindowText   = API.new('GetWindowText', 'LPI', 'I', 'user32')
EnumWindowsProc = API::Callback.new('LP', 'I'){ |handle, param|
  buf = "\0" * 200
  GetWindowText.call(handle, buf, 200);

  if (!buf.index(param).nil?)
    puts "window was found: handle #{handle}"
    0 # stop looking after we find it
  else
    1
  end
}

EnumWindows.call(EnumWindowsProc, 'Firefox')
```

Comment: it works perfect!  I have always been using `require 'Win32API'` and it seems that `win32/api` and `WIN32API` are different.  Does any one know a place for documentation and examples?  The main site seems to be http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=85

Answer (score 2):

The 1st argument of `FindWindow` searches by class name, if you use `"Notepad"` (Notepad's main window class name) for this and a null title you would get the 1st matching handle irrespective of its caption.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly want to use the [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(VS.85).aspx) function; this function will call you back with a window handle, and then you can use [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520(VS.85).aspx) to inspect the window title and find the one you want.

Now, I have no idea how to write a callback function in Ruby, so you'll need some help there.

Comment: yeah, I wonder too... that the Win32 callback function is expected to be a C function probably, so how can it call a Ruby function