# Ruby - passing a method to a DLL library as a callback

Tags: c++, c, ruby, dll

Let's say I have a C/C++ library with this function, compiled to a DLL:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall myFunction(void (*myCallback)(int)) {
    int result = MessageBox(
        0, (LPCWSTR)L"Press yes or no", (LPCWSTR)L"Test", MB_YESNO
    );
    myCallback(result);
}
```

It just opens standard Win32 message box and passes the result to a callback function.

The question is: is it possible to use this function in Ruby, via Fiddle or something similar, and pass a Ruby method to it somehow so it is called from within the C++ code?

Here is the code I use to import DLL library to Ruby:

```rb
require "fiddle"

myLibrary = Fiddle.dlopen("myLibrary.dll")
myFunction = Fiddle::Function.new(
  myLibrary["myFunction"], 
  [Fiddle::TYPE_VOIDP], 
  Fiddle::TYPE_VOID
)

def myCallback(value)
  puts "MessageBox result is #{value}"
end
```

And this obviously doesn't work:

```rb
myFunction.call(method(:myCallback))
```

It just throws a TypeError - can't convert Method to Integer.

Is there a way to pass the callback to the C function?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327666/win32s-findwindow-can-find-a-particular-window-with-the-exact-title-but-what  The link describes how you can use Ruby to call an API function that requires a callback.  So you can probably use that as a guide.

Comment: The tests include [a `qsort()` example](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ae048b1b7c0b1e632d97c448518932dc53f8cae6/test/fiddle/test_func.rb#L72-L90). Also take a look at `Fiddle::Importer#bind`.

Comment: Thank you for the qsort() example! Fiddle::Closure seems to be the right thing for callbacks :)

Answer (score 4):

So I found the solution:

```
myClosure = Class.new(Fiddle::Closure) {
  def call(value)
    puts "MessageBox result is #{value}"  
  end
}.new(Fiddle::TYPE_VOID, [Fiddle::TYPE_INT])
```

Then I can simply call the C function:

```
myFunction.call(myClosure)
```

I don't really know how this works - but it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative syntax is to use Fiddle's `BlockCaller`:

```
myClosure = Fiddle::Closure::BlockCaller.new(Fiddle::TYPE_VOID, [Fiddle::TYPE_INT]) do |value|
  puts "MessageBox result is #{value}"
end
```