# Ruby - accessing instance methods / variables from anonymous class

Tags: ruby, closures, anonymous-class

I have following Ruby code:

```
class Baz
    def foo()
        qux = Class.new() {
            def call()
                bar()
            end
        }.new()
        qux.call()
    end
    def bar()
        puts "bar"
    end
end

b = Baz.new()
b.foo()
```

How can I access method `bar` from the anonymous class, that means from `qux.call`? Is it possible?

I'm keeping getting this message:

```
classes-test.rb:5:in `call': undefined method `bar' for #<#<Class:0x00000002d9c248>:0x00000002d9c1a8> (NoMethodError)
```

I'm new to Ruby, so any advice or even deeper explanation of the problem will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.bar` is an instance method of `Baz`, you need to have an instance of `Baz` available in your context to call `.bar`. You can do that by passing the instance object to the class on initialization, so you can call its `.bar` method on it.

This works:

```
class Baz
  def foo
    qux = Class.new do
      def initialize(a)  
        @a = a  
      end  

      def call
        @a.bar
      end
    end.new(self)

    qux.call
  end

  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end

b = Baz.new
b.foo
=> 'bar'
```

If you need to pass a `class` to `Class.new()` as you mention in the comments, you can override the initializer method like this (please note that you may have to consider the arguments that your Closure class initialize needs for `super`:

```
qux = Class.new(Fiddle::Closure) do
  def initialize(baz)  
    @baz = baz
    super
  end  

  def call
    @baz.bar
  end
end.new(self)
```

On a side note, you don't need all those `()`, it's [Ruby style](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) to omit them if not needed.

Comment: Is it possible without the constructor, somehow? Actually, in real-world application I need to use this with `Class.new(Fiddle::Closure)` (to create callbacks for C DLL library, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819592/ruby-passing-a-method-to-a-dll-library-as-a-callback?noredirect=1#comment45911791_28819592) and overriding the constructor wouldn't be much comfortable in this case.

Comment: Why not? You can override the constructor calling `super` to respect what it did before: `def initialize(a); @a = a; super; end`

Comment: If you don't actually want an instance method, you can make it a class method, basically just a 'function', that you can call from anywhere without  instantiating an object first. But instance methods belong to objects, you always need to instantiate an object of the class, and have a reference to it, to call an instance method on that particular instance. That's how instance methods work.