# Get processID using part of WINDOW heading

Tags: c++

i use the following program in c++ ,in Visual C++ 6.0, to inform me with message box when the MS Paint program is opened.   It uses the exact name of the WINDOW of MS Paint,which is "Untitled - Paint" .  However now i need to make the program inform me with message box  when i know only a part of the name of the actual WINDOW , for example , if the window is "Abcdefgh - Paint" and i set the string name in this way -  std::wstring windowName(L"Paint"); - the program to work again.  Using the following  3 rows of code the program works fine when the actual WINDOW name is the exact name of the MS Paint window:

```
HWND windowHandle = FindWindowW(NULL, windowName.c_str());
DWORD* processID = new DWORD;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, processID);
```

But it will not work  if the string  windowName  is just part of the name, i mean if it is  "Paint".
Can someone show me how to do this? I thought to take a list of the names of all opened WINDOWS and to compare them with my part of the real name, i mean to search match of the substring "Paint" in their names, but i don't know how to get all opened windows.
Also, this is very important, my computer is old and i am using Visual C++ 6.0, so i can not use all the evolution features of C++ and the program environments nowadays, i mean , i can not use code which is compiled correctly in .NET but does not compiles in Visual C++ 6.0. 
 Thanks

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include < iostream>
#include < string>
#include < windows.h>
#include < sstream> 
#include < ctime>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                 int       nCmdShow)
{
// TODO: Place code here.
std::wstring windowName(L"Untitled - Paint");




while(true)
{

    Sleep(1000*5);

time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
int tday = now->tm_mday;
int tmin = now->tm_min;
int thour = now->tm_hour;


HWND windowHandle = FindWindowW(NULL, windowName.c_str());
DWORD* processID = new DWORD;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, processID);

char probaintstr[20];
sprintf(probaintstr,"%d",*processID);





if(strlen(probaintstr) <=5 ) 
{

Sleep(1000*10);

MessageBox(NULL,"niama go Notepad ili Wordpad","zaglavie",MB_OK);
}
else {

}




}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Win32's FindWindow() can find a particular window with the exact title, but what about "try.bat - Notepad"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327666/win32s-findwindow-can-find-a-particular-window-with-the-exact-title-but-what)

Comment: Don't leak memory by allocating a `new DWORD` for `processID` each iteration. Just make it a local variable, `DWORD processID;`, then use the `&` operator to get a pointer to it: `GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, &processID);`  Then you can use it later without dereferencing (like anormal `DWORD` value, without using `*`).  It's not a big problem in your example, because `DWORD`s are small and the iteration period is long, but you don't want to get into the habit of creating leaky apps.

Comment: In fact, don't even iterate. Polling is bad. It always leads you to choose arbitrary values to throw at `Sleep`, and no matter which one you pick, you'll always get it wrong. Use [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) instead, and have the OS call you back, whenever a top-level window is created. This won't needlessly burn resources. And you will no longer miss windows that are created and destroyed between two sampling points (as is the case with polling).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EnumWindows`, for example

```
BOOL CALLBACK enumWindow(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lp)
{
    std::string str(512, 0);
    int len = GetWindowText(hwnd, &str[0], str.size());
    if (str.find("Paint") != std::string::npos)
    {
        MessageBox(0, str.c_str(), 0, 0);
    }
    return true;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    EnumWindows(enumWindow, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can use `FindWindowEx` and look for classname. The classname for MS Paint is `"MSPaintApp"`. You can find this information from "Spy" utility for windows.

```
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    for (HWND hwnd = NULL;;)
    {
        hwnd = FindWindowExA(NULL, hwnd, "MSPaintApp", 0);
        if (!hwnd)
            break;

        std::string str(512, 0);
        int len = GetWindowText(hwnd, &str[0], 512);
        str.resize(len);
        if (str.find("Paint") != std::string::npos)
            MessageBox(0, str.c_str(), 0, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For process id you don't need to allocate memory. Just use a reference:

```
DWORD processID;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, &processID);
```